# Replacing Double Quotation to Single Quotation is SQLITE

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

How can I replace double quotes with single quotes:

I've tried:

```
UPDATE table SET COLUMN=REPLACE(COLUMN,'''',''')
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quote. Try

```
UPDATE your_table SET col = REPLACE(col, '''''' ,'''')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET COLUMN=REPLACE(COLUMN,'''''','''')
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/798f2/5)

We have to escape the single quote. If you want to write `'` you have to write `''`. For more [see this.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q14)